# Open left navigation of ons-split-view page as main page in mobile portrait mode

Tags: mobile, split, onsen-ui, landscape-portrait

I am working in Onsen UI Split [View](https://onsen.io/reference/ons-split-view.html) Page. Every thing working perfectly in "Landscape Mode". I want when ons-split-view page is open in mobile device "Portrait Mode" then Left Navigation is work as main page and when we click any link then another page opens with Back Button on top for go back to left navigation page.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually what you want to do is not something which the split view is intended to be able to do.

Probably the easiest thing to do is look into [`ons-sliding-menu`](https://onsen.io/reference/ons-sliding-menu.html). In Onsen 2 actually these two components have been merged into a new one called [`ons-splitter`](https://onsen.io/2/reference/ons-splitter.html). The functionality may not be exactly what you want but it's similar and probably easy to use.

The other option may require some more effort. The easiest thing you could do is just write some css which does what you want:

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
  .onsen-split-view__secondary {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    display: block !important;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100% !important;
    transition: 0.2s transform ease-in;
  }
  .onsen-split-view__secondary.closed {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
```

And also you can add a backbutton to your main pages and make it visible only in portrait. What you want is that when you click a menu item it adds the `closed` class from the element and when you click the backbutton it removes it.

If you want you could also consider moving to Onsen 2 where the `ons-splitter` already does these types of things out of the box.